# Does gpu supported versions also support cpu

Tags: tensorflow

If i choose to install the version of tensorflow which supports gpu will I also be able to run it on cpu? I have a computer which i do most of my programming and another that i would like to run my tensorflow program on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I you will install GPU version, you will be able to run your code on CPU as well.

Comment: do i have to specify which processor to use, cpu or gpu, or will it pick automatically

Comment: @Drok_ you can specify it with `tf.device`